# Axios POST request returns attachment, Storing it gives mulformed file Exception in Node.js

Tags: node.js, laravel, sqlite, axios, fs

I have a POST route, that returns attachment. The issues is, when i call the route it executes properly but after storing the attachment to local storage using `fs` Node gives **Mulformed File Exception**. I'm getting the `sqlite3` database as a response attachment and can't read after storing it using `fs`. The idea is to download the file from the server and put it on local storage as restored copy for Node application.

Axios Function

---

```js
function restoreDatabase(PATH , UID , TOKEN , URL){
return new Promise((resolve , reject) => {
        axios({
            URL,
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: 'document',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': TOKEN
            },
            data: {
                uid: UID
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            fs.writeFile(PATH , response.data , (err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve();
            })
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        })
    });
}
```

Here is what i got from response,

```
SQLite format 3@ $$.4 ��< � o��W�>''�;tablepayment_modespayment_modes CREATE TABLE
`payment_modes` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` text, 
`is_details_required` boolean, `is_runtime` boolean, `additional` text, `created_at` datetime not
null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�9�ItablechallanchallanCREATE TABLE `challan` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `customer_id` integer, `taxable` float, `due_date` date, `payment_date` date, `status` undefined, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�} ))�5tablepurchase_partypurchase_partyCREATE TABLE `purchase_party` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255), `phone` varchar(255), `address` varchar(255), `business` varchar(255), `gst` varchar(255) default 'NA', `state_id` integer, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)� �tablesalessales CREATE TABLE `sales` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `paymentable_type` integer, `paymentable_id` integer, `product_id` integer, `price` float, `qty` integer, `discount` float, `cgst` float, `sgst` float, `igst` float, `taxable` float, `_ref` integer, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�^�tableinvoiceinvoice    CREATE TABLE `invoice` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `customer_id` integer, `taxable` float, `due_date` date, `payment_date` date, `paymentmode_id` integer, `additional` text, `iid` text, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�]�tablesettingsettingCREATE TABLE `setting` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `title` varchar(255), `info` text, `key` varchar(255), `value` text, `type` varchar(255), `category` varchar(255), `additional` text, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)��tablestockstockCREATE TABLE `stock` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `product_id` integer, `stock` integer default '0', `status` integer, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�1�5tableproductsproductsCREATE TABLE `products` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255), `price` float default '0', `UOM1` integer, `UOM2` integer, `conversion` float default '1', `UOM` integer, `tax` float default '0', `hsn` varchar(255) default 'NA', `discount` float default '0', `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�f�+tableunitsunitsCREATE TABLE `units` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)�n�+tablecustomerscustomersCREATE TABLE `customers` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255), `phone` varchar(255), `address` varchar(255), `business` varchar(255), `gst` varchar(255) default 'NA', `state_id` integer, `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)P++Ytablesqlite_sequencesqlite_sequenceCREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)��tablestatesstatesCREATE TABLE `states` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `name` varchar(255), `prefix` varchar(255), `code` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `updated_at` datetime not null default CURRENT_TIMES %�r-��y< � � � S ��T��b& � � x ?    �   �   S   ��^��X
```

And after writing the Axios `response.body` to file, This is the error i got by reading the `sqlite3` database.

[image: Reading Error]

I've tried with the `responseType` as `blob` and `document` in axios function, but bot gives the same error.

Here are the headers and response returned by the server,
[image: The Response]
[image: The Response Headers]

The backend is Laravel and it  returns the storage file as given,

```php
return response()->file(storage_path('app/backups/RtyhguRvB8YbdhE.sqlite' , [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-sqlite3',
    'Content-Disposition' =>  'attachment;filename=gstpro.sqlite'
]);
```

As per the received headers from the server, I noticed that server compresses the file by `gzip` compression. Let me know if there is some workaround.